# Loading a class from a different package?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I'm currently making a Java program that loads classes from a different package. It allows users to delete .class files from a package and prevent a crash. I therefore want to load all these classes using:

```
Class.forName("this.is.a.package.RandomClass");
```

The only problem is that when I try that it says that the class is not found. If I put the class in the same package it works, but if I wanted to load it from the package "this.is.a" Class.forName("this.is.a.package.RandomClass"), it doesn't work. Any help appreciated!

I know I should probably be using URLClassLoaders but I don't know how I would use them to load a file inside a zipped jar.

Comment: If you want to load class `RandomClass` which is in package `this.is.a.package`, then you have to use `Class.forName("this.is.a.package.RandomClass");`

Comment: I just tried that again. I have no clue why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: I figured out a solution for this, I will post the answer when I can, for anyone else to stumble onto this